# Order of polynomials in finite fields

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\mathbb{F_q}$ be a finite field of characteristic $p$ and let $f\in \mathbb{F_q}$ be a polynomial of positive degree with $f(0)\not=0$. Prove that $ord(f(x^p))=p \, \, ord(f(x))$.

Definition. Let $f\in \mathbb{F_q}$ be a nonzero polynomial. If $f(0)\not=0$. then the least positive integer $e$ for which $f(x)$ divides $x^e-1$ is called the order of $f$ y denoted by $ord(f)=ord(f(x))$. If $f(0)=0$, then $f(x)=x^h g(x)$, where $h\in \mathbb{N}$ y $g\in \mathbb{F_q}[x]$ with $g(0)\not=0$ are determined; $ord(f)$ is then defined to be $ord(g)$.

My attempt.

Let $e=ord(f)$ then $f(x)$ divides $x^e-1$, so $f(x^p)$ divides $x^{pe}-1$. Thus $ord(f(x^p))$ divides $pe$.

However, I do not know how to prove equality. I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x^p)$ divides $x^n - 1$ then $n$ is divisible by $p$ (otherwise $x^n - 1$ would only have simple roots, but the formal derivative of $f(x^p)$ is $0$ so any root of $f(x^p)$ will have multiplicity larger than $1$, and all roots of $f(x^p)$ are roots of $x^n - 1$). Then let $n = kp$.

Therefore $f(x^p)$ divides $(x^p)^k - 1$ which means there is a $g \in \mathbb{F}_q[x]$ such that $(x^p)^k - 1 = g(x)f(x^p)$.

Taking formal derivatives we find $0 = g'(x)f(x^p) + g(x)0 = g'(x)f(x^p)$ which means $g'(x) = 0$ (because $f \neq 0$). Then $g(x) = h(x^p)$ for some $h \in \mathbb{F}_q[x]$.

Therefore, $(x^p)^k - 1 = h(x^p)f(x^p)$ and so $u^k - 1 = h(u)f(u)$ because this is an identity of polynomials in $u = x^p$.

Thus $f$ divides $x^k - 1$ and $k \geq ord(f) = e$.

Comment: Why if $f(x^p)$ divides $x^n-1$ then $f(x)^p$ divides $x^n-1$?, by hypothesis $f\in \mathbb{F_q}$.

Comment: You are right I was thinking of $\mathbb{F}_p$...

Comment: I made fixes, but will keep checking for other mistakes.

Comment: Tob Ernack apparently everything is fine. Thank you very much for your help.